# How to do array operation of a cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, my dataframe looks like this:

```
id   |   refers 
----------------
1    |   [2,3]
2    |   [1,3]
3    |   []
```

I want to add another column which show how many times that id is referred by another id. For example:

```
id   |   refers  |  referred_count
----------------------------------
1    |   [2,3]   |   1
2    |   [1,3]   |   1
3    |   []      |   2
```

My current code looks like this:

```
citations_dict = {}
for index, row in data_ref.iterrows():
    if len(row['reference_list']) > 0:
        for reference in row['reference_list']:
            if reference not in citations_dict:
                citations_dict[reference] = {}
                d = data_ref.loc[data_ref['id'] == reference]
                citations_dict[reference]['venue'] = d['venue']
                citations_dict[reference]['reference'] = d['reference']
                citations_dict[reference]['citation'] = 1
            else:
                citations_dict[reference]['citation'] += 1
```

The problem is that, this code takes so long. I am wondering how to do it faster, maybe using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Get the count of each ID in the refers column and store it in a dictionary and apply the function on creating new column.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'refers':[[2,3],[1,3],[]]})
counter = dict(Counter([item for sublist in df['refers'] for item in sublist]))
df['refer_counts'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: counter[x])
```

output

```
   id  refers  refer_counts
0   1  [2, 3]             1
1   2  [1, 3]             1
2   3      []             2
```

Think it's exactly what you needed!

Comment: Sorry for the long accept, I somehow managed to find a way, but your answer is also correct

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'refers': [[1,2,3], [1,3], []]})
    id  refers     referred_count
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   2   [1, 3]      1
2   3   []          2
```

Create a dictionary of the number of occurrences of refers:

```
refer_count = df.refers.apply(pd.Series).stack()\
                .reset_index(drop=True)\
                .astype(int)\
                .value_counts()\
                .to_dict()
```

Subtract the refer in each id by its refer_count:

```
df['referred_count'] = df.apply(lambda x: refer_count[x['id']] - x['refers'].count(x['id']), axis = 1)
```

**Output**:

```
    id  refers    referred_count
0   1   [1, 2, 3]  1
1   2   [1, 3]     1
2   3   []         2
```

Comment: I think, That's way too complicated !

Comment: But it takes care of the hidden case where `id` refers itself

Answer (score 1):

First create a helper `Series` using [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

This will be the values of your column 'referred_count' with `id` as the index.

Then you can `reset_index` of df to `id` for easy merge of this series, and finally `reset_index` to get DataFrame back to original shape.

```
s = pd.Series(np.hstack(df['refers'])).value_counts()
df.set_index('id').assign(referred_count=s).reset_index()
```

[out]

```
   id  refers  referred_count
0   1  [2, 3]               1
1   2  [1, 3]               1
2   3      []               2
```